# Database Custom Profiler FOr .Net or Java

Tags: c#, java, .net, sql, mysql

Microsoft provided us a way to create our own profiler by using Microsft.* namespaces. I can trace all queries going to any MS SQL instance. I need to do this on MySQL as well. Is there any api available for .net or java to do this? If anyone can provide also a working code is very much appreciated thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditionally p6spy has been used for wrapping a JDBC-connection in Java to help analyze and debug said connection, for instance printing out all SQL going to the database.  See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=p6spy for questions about p6spy.

http://www.p6spy.com/

Comment: I needed something I can embed in my application.

Comment: p6spy is a JDBC-driverwrapper you embed in your own application, and wrap another JDBC-driver with (previously used in your application).